# When using OkHttp on the server, what's a common directory to store cached responses?

Tags: java, okhttp

I've seen some people reference `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`.  Is that sufficient, or is another place preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you control the server? My recommendation is ~/okhttp/cache which likely has better access controls than the temp directory.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and see how far it takes me.